# ReactJS push to state array replaces every exisitng value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I want to push an 2d array into the end of a state. But somehow, when i log the state every time it changes with a useEffect, i replaces every existing array with the new one.

The variable "position" is my 2d array, also a state. Might this cause any reference problems?
I have no idea and im starting to lose my mind about this...

```
const [positionList, setPositionList] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = [...positionList, position]
    setPositionList(updatePosition);
}, [playerTurn])
```

expected output (or what i want)

```
positionList = [position1, position2, position3, //and so on]
```

but what i get is this (lets say i try to push the array three times)

```
positionList = [position3, position3, position3]
```

**EDIT:**
So, after some good ideas from the community, i found out that i had to copy my array i want to push (the "position") before i push it into the state. So my working code looks now like this:

```
const [positionList, setPositionList] = useState([])
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    let positionCopy = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
        positionCopy[i] = position[i].slice();
    }
    setPositionList([...positionList, positionCopy]);
}
```

Comment: "lets say i try to push the array three times" how did you do that?

Comment: @AnoopJoshiP With the useEffect. Im making a chess game and after every move (so after every change of "playerTurn") i want to push the current position into positionList

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `positionList` as a dependency of your `useEffect` callback, so the `positionList` captured by the callback doesn't necessarily reflect the latest value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // return early if the update already happened to prevent recursion
    const updatePosition = [...positionList, position]
    setPositionList(updatePosition);
}, [playerTurn, positionList])
```

TBH, using `useEffect` to update a state hook is difficult to maintain and prone to accidental recursive behaviour.

You might get better mileage by using a state reducer with the `useReducer` hook. For anything beyond trivial state management, the `useReducer` hook is worth getting to grips with.

Comment: A decent `useReducer` tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-usereducer-hook-ultimate-guide/

Comment: I've never worked with useReducer yet and i feel like its a bit too much since i basically only what a few arrays inside my state, but i give it a shot. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Changed the useState to useReducer, still get the same output. Probalby because i still havent added the positionList dependency to the useEffect. How can i check and return earyl if the update already happend? because otherwise i get an infinite rerender (as u mentioned)

Comment: @mattisvensson Unfortunately, the level of detail provided in your question means that it is difficult to present any alternatives. You'll need to supply a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want a better answer. Ping me here if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 const [positionList, setPositionList] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
     setPositionList(state=> [...state, position]);
 }, [playerTurn])
```

Comment: Already tried this and unfortunately it doenst help...